# Bash get list of zip files in dir and perform some operations on each of them

Tags: bash, loops

I have a bash script, which goes through list of directories and if some directory contains zip files it bind zip file name into variable and perform some actions over it and then goes to another in this dir. Unfortunately, it works when there is one zip file per directory. If more - it gives error "Binary operator expected"

Script:

```
    if [ -e $currdir/*.zip ]; then 
        for file in $currdir/*.zip; do
            echo the zip is "${file##*/}"
        done
```

Please help me to rework script accordingly.

Comment: `-e` checks a single file, `$currdir/*.zip` expands to every file that ends in `.zip`.  Maybe try a loop?

Comment: Can you give a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
for file in "$currdir"/*.zip; do
  [ -e "$file" ] || continue
  echo the zip is "${file##*/}"
done
```

As pointed out in the comments the glob will happen in the shell, then `[` is called with the output, i.e:

```
[ -e * ]
```

will become:

```
[ -e Desktop Documents Downloads ... ]
```

Therefore trying to expand and checking in the for iteration will work.

Please see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs

Comment: I mean the `-e` is pretty much redundant as it has already matched in the glob...

Comment: @123 Except that when a glob is not matched it will expand literally, i.e: `echo this_will_not_match_*` will print `this_will_not_match_*`. Unless the shell option `nullglob` is set.

Answer (score 1):

If you need exactly check then you can use:

```
if [[ -n $(echo "$currdir"/*.zip) ]]; then
  for f in "$currdir"/*.zip; do
   echo "Processing $f file..";
  done
fi
```

But I'd prefer just looping over files that contain *.zip extension:

```
for f in "$currdir"/*.zip; do
   echo "Processing $f file..";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `case` construct is too often overlooked.

```
  case *.jpg in *.jpg ) echo found files ;; * ) echo no files found  ;; esac
```

produces the correct message in my dir with 1000s+ jpgs ;-)

Change both references from `jpg` to `zip` and see if it works for you.

IHTH